# D3 ticks every 4 months but starting in first domain date

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wan to create a line chart in d3,but i want to show ticks every 4 months because I need to show ticks every point that I have data in the chart.

I used this:

```
// xScale is a time scale obj d3.time.scale()

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.time.months, 4)
  .orient('bottom');
```

ant this works, but the ticks show 2 days after the initial date in my data:

> It show at 1/January/2015 when the first data is in 30/December/2014

How can I set the initial tick in an specific point and the set 4 months interval?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the d3 time scale will try to space the dates evenly (and I'm not sure there is a way to specify specific dates). If you know exactly which dates you want displayed, you can use an [Ordinal Scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) with dates as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify exactly which tick values you want displayed with [`axis.tickValues`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues). For example, in one of my projects I want only the Monday of every week displayed as a tick, and this is a sample of my code:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis();
xAxis.scale(xScale);

var xAxisTicks = [];

var xAxisTickInterval = 7;
var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

var currentMonday = new Date(currentStartTime);
while (currentMonday.getTime() <= currentEndTime)
{
    var currentMondayCopy = new Date(currentMonday.getTime());
    xAxisTicks.push(currentMondayCopy);

    currentMonday.setTime(currentMonday.getTime() + xAxisTickInterval * millisecondsPerDay);
}

xAxis.tickValues(xAxisTicks);
```

where `currentStartTime` (always guaranteed to be a Monday) and `currentEndTime` are the bounds on the "window" of time my graph is currently displaying, in JavaScript's internal millisecond representation of times.